# Can't find setting.py and manage.py in my PyCharm project

Tags: django, pycharm

Can't find setting.py and manage.py in my Django PyCharm project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In settings - Languages & Frameworks - Django, you can set manually the location of your settings file and your manage.py.